# Windows authentication mode in case of major failure

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a new Access Control System and as per manufacturer recommendations, I am supposed to choose "Windows Authentication Mode" when installing the SQL server on to a remote machine.

That sounds like the best option in terms of security.
But what happens if the machine dies and all I am left with is a backup of that database?
How am I supposed to recover the data from that database if the only way to authenticate is by using the original Windows credentials/token?

Comment: SQL Server authentication and Windows authentication are not mutually exclusive. You can have accounts for both.

Comment: You can just restore the database to another server, and as `sa` you would have full access. You would only be (sort of) stuck if you had no backup and you lost admin access to the machine.

Answer (score 2):

If the machine dies and all you have is a backup, you install SQL Server on the replacement machine. The new SQL Server installation will have at least one admin account (`sa`) that you use just long enough to create a new admin before disabling. The new admin account will be able to restore your old database backup, as well as assign new user permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event of being left alone with only a backup and no SQL Server machine available, you can:

1. Prepare a new VM and install SQL Server (same or newer version)

- It should be the same edition or better because you can't easily restore Enterprise edition on Standard edition or cheaper.
- Whether you choose Mixed authentication or Windows only is irrelevant. The account(s) you add if any or SA if mixed mode will be there with `sysadmin` role once installed

2. Copy your backup file to it and restore it using an account added during the installation

- They can restore it because they are members of `sysadmin`

Among other things, you may have to deal with master key if encryption is used

Your data are now available to the user(s) created during the installation.

You should check your DB then:

1. Update compatibility level (if newer SQL Server version)
2. Check DB with `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE`
3. Update Stats (full scan)
4. Check DB with `DBCC CHECKDB (<db>) WITH DATA_PURITY, ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS`

If users and applications need access:

- Create Login(s) (Windows or SQL Auth, contained user don't need that)
- Fix orphan user for SQL Auth

Other things may include (not limited to) jobs, server roles, permissions, security, ...

Answer (score -1):

when is referred to use **Windows authentication** method, is not referred to as a local windows account, is making reference to make use of an AD account, this can be in preference **an Active Directory group**, you configure your SQL Server instance to allow to **authenticate thru the AD group**, which at the end of the day is using valid credentials that are constantly being rotated (changed) with the AD that is why is considered more secure. if the server dies, you can take the backup of your database, build a new server and restore it.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16